# Extend/splice 12/2 romex along concrete finished wall

Tags: electrical, concrete, receptacle

I would like to extend some wiring for a counter outlet that is running behind a refrigerator, which currently encased in a metal "cable concealer" raceway. Note: wiring is in a raceway because most of the walls in my apartment are solid concrete - which is the main problem I'm facing.

The wires need to be extended to move the raceway and its outlet up about 1.5 ft so I can under-mount a low profile outlet below the cabinet instead of having a large box+outlet jutting out from the (concrete) wall. (Also I'm tiling a backsplash and the outlet+raceway are unsightly).

Are there any possible methods to extend this wiring on the finished concrete wall without a face mounted junction box sticking out? Ideally I would run a whole new length of wiring, but I'm not sure where the closest junction is located (wiring disappears within a false wall). Thanks!

Comment: Do you rent this apartment?

Comment: I own it. I wouldn't upgrade anything to a rental...

Comment: Good to know that you own. One way to help eliminate the unsightly look of surface mounted raceways is to build out on the concrete wall surface. You install furring strips to the concrete and then drywall over that. Before mounting the drywall you install electrical boxes that can be 2 inches deep (1.5" furring strips plus 0.5" drywall). When done the wall looks like a normal wall with cover plates on the necessary electrical boxes.

Comment: Good idea, although I'd rather not loose any wall thickness.

I looked into the outlet for the refrigerator (which is near the raceway going into the false wall) and found another set of wires and splices in there. So I cut power and checked continuity between the spliced hot and the outlet along the wall - they're the same! So I'll just run a new length from that box over to the cabinet. Thanks!

Comment: Is this raceway an actual *surface raceway*, or just a "cord concealer"? You can't put NM in the latter (doubt it will fit, from the cord concealers I've used for audio cables and such), and the former is generally used with THHN

Comment: Check that continuity with the breaker OFF... otherwise you may have simply detected two different circuits that are on the same pole...

Comment: It is a surface raceway with 12/2 romex - not a A/V or extension cord concealer.

I did check continuity with the power off